# JS/HTML - One Page Apps - Cancelling asynchronous actions

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asynchronous

I'm working on a one page application. First time I'm building proper one page applications and stumbling in a few gotchas.

---

Each page has a set of asynchronous operations that could be triggered. The actions can take up to 30 seconds.

It is likely the user will change the page causing the asynchronous operations to fail upon completion.

The page HTML is re-rendered each time a page changes, so actions fail to due to missing DOM elements and/or other resources/variables. Also variables and other resources may change due to the change in state.

How do you generally deal with this sort of problem?

---

I believe that it is almost impossible to cancel an ongoing request unless it's split in checkpoints, where checks are made before continuing.

I guess some options would be:

1. End each function with an `active page` check. This would have to be done at checkpoints before interacting with each resource in order to prevent unwanted behavior.
2. Catch the exceptions and let them fail silently

---

Any thoughts? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use events? Emit an event when you want to cancel the request, and have the request listen for the event / be ready to handle its stop gracefully.

```
function Potato {
  this.running = true;
}

Potato.prototype.stop = function () {
  this.running = false;
}

Potato.prototype.dostuff = function () {
  var things = [1, 2, 3];

  Object.keys(things).forEach(function(k) {
    if (!this.running) {
      break;
    }
    console.log(k);
  });
}

var potato = new Potato;
potato.on('stop', potato.stop);
this.emit('stop');
```

Sorry, not exactly clean code, but you get the idea?

Comment: thanks for the reply. This is what I meant by `checkpoints`. Thanks for the example though. I'm using something similar as well. :)

Comment: Glad we reached the same conclusion; you should totally gist your actual implementation so I can take a look :P

Answer (score 0):

1. If it's a one-page app, how can users change the page?
2. As with any UX decision, it's all about feedback... you have to make the user aware of what's going on. If the user can keep moving while the page performs some action, then you need to either alert the user that taking other actions will abandon the changes they made, or prevent them from doing other actions until the present action is completed. If the latter, it's not uncommon to create a "processing" flag in your code that gets triggered when an action is started, and cleared when the action is complete. That way, if the user attempts other interactivity that would interrupt the action, you can handle it before allowing the user's newest action to complete by checking to see if anything is currently processing. (Zipp's example, above, illustrates that tactic.)

Comment: One-Page meaning that the DOM isn't `completely` reloaded by the browser. Pages are loaded within the Page via ajax.

Comment: Regarding the feedback I prefer the users are able to change the page when they need to instead of locking up the interface. :)

Comment: When you load in the new pages via ajax, are you discarding the former contents? Another option would be to hide the old contents, leave them in the DOM, but add the new content in without removing the old. It's a little trickier (as you have to manage virtual page-states, hiding and showing them as the user moves around the system), but at least transactions that are still outstanding would have DOM elements to attach to, if needed.

Comment: Yes, that's a great idea. Unfortunately I'm developing a Win8 app using WinJS Navigate module which replaces all the content.

Comment: Ah. Context is everything. If I'd know this was WinJS / Win8, I'd have kept mum, as I haven't tried dealing with that, yet. Sorry. You should include that information in your original question.